# Is it easier to create a class that inherits ObservableCollection<object>?

Tags: c#, .net

Right... This is a weird question...

```
private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<object>> _groups = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<object>>();
```

Is it easier to create a class that inherits ObservableCollection?

Also I want a property Group that has that type.

Any suggestions?

Comment: An `ObservableCollection` of `ObservableCollection`s?  It will definitely be easier to write a class to manage it.

Comment: @Andrew yes. It is for WPF...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find it easier to work with just an ObservableCollection of Objects and use this with [ListViewCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.aspx/) class which allows you to navigate and display the source collection based on sort, filter, and **group** queries, all without having to manipulate the underlying source collection itself.

Answer (score 4):

I'm gonna assume that you have a really good reason to use an ObservableCollection of ObservableCollections and can't refactor to a simpler type. :)

Deriving a class is nice and easy:

```
public class CollectionCollection : ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Object>>
{
}
```

But if you're only using that particular type in one spot and don't want the overhead (such as there is) of an entirely new class, you can always use type aliases:

```
namespace MyProgram
{
    using CollectionCollection = ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Object>>;

    public class MyClass
    {
        CollectionCollection _groups = new CollectionCollection();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using a collection that contains collections in some sort of a clipboard manager i'm trying to make... Making some sort of a history. The group is for multiple things in clipboard...

Comment: I also use a separate file for my class. Seems easier for me, but I wouldn't want to have a file that contains only some usings and just a single line so the second option could be the one for me. Thanks!